# SAML Verification using java

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, unmarshalling, opensaml

public class SAMLResponseVerifier {

```
public static boolean validateToken(String samlResponse) throws SecurityException, 
ValidationException, ConfigurationException, UnmarshallingException, 
CertificateException, KeyException, org.opensaml.xml.security.SecurityException, 
ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, InitializationException {
    
     InitializationService.initialize();
     DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
     DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
     Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(samlResponse)));
     /*This will give the XML with outerElement. Use responseElement.getAttribute("ID") if 
     specific elements are needed */
     Element responseElement = document.getDocumentElement();

     System.out.println("Response: " + responseElement);         
     ResponseUnmarshaller responseUnmarshaller = new ResponseUnmarshaller();
     Response response = (Response) responseUnmarshaller.unmarshall(responseElement);

      SignableSAMLObject samlToken = response;
      samlToken.validate(true);
      Signature signature=samlToken.getSignature();
      KeyInfo keyInfo=signature.getKeyInfo();
      X509Certificate pubKey=(X509Certificate)KeyInfoHelper.getCertificates(keyInfo).get(0);
      BasicX509Credential cred=new BasicX509Credential();
      cred.setEntityCertificate((java.security.cert.X509Certificate) pubKey);
      cred.setEntityId("signing-entity-ID");
      ArrayList<Credential> trustedCredentials=new ArrayList<Credential>();
      trustedCredentials.add(cred);
      CollectionCredentialResolver credResolver=new CollectionCredentialResolver(trustedCredentials);
      KeyInfoCredentialResolver kiResolver=SecurityHelper.buildBasicInlineKeyInfoResolver();
      ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine engine=new ExplicitKeySignatureTrustEngine(credResolver,kiResolver);
      CriteriaSet criteriaSet=new CriteriaSet();
      criteriaSet.add(new EntityIDCriteria("signing-entity-ID"));
      System.out.println("Token Validation :" + engine.validate(signature,criteriaSet));
      return engine.validate(signature,criteriaSet);
    }
```

}
This is the code I have for SAML response verification.
But I am getting one error during the unmarshalling process.

org.opensaml.xml.io.UnmarshallingException: Unable to located builder for {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol}Response

Not able to figure out where I am going wrong.